# Does CiviMail have an upper limit for total recipients in an email blast?

Tags: civimail, email, evaluating-civicrm

I have a client that would like to create an email blast to 50,000 or so constituents, and we are currently evaluating CiviCRM to handle this. I've noticed the documentation says that CiviMail is good for email blasts sent to over 50 constituents, but I can't find any mention of whether or not there is an upper limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - that can be done - the 50 is just a reference to the Search -> Find Contact screen -> Search -> Select -> Actions -> EMail send now (to 50 or less) option.

When sending out lots of CiviMail to lots of CiviContacts best to use an external SMTP service to help you with the Email delivery - and to minimize the risk that your webserver will be blacklisted.

**UPDATE** an actual number from one of my clients' civicrm tables -> intended recipients: **89419** And I'm sure there were larger mailings.

Comment: I've not done much yet - let me dig up an actual number for you - give me a second...

Comment: Ok added a real number for you! Hopefully that will give you some confidence in CiviMail.

Comment: That's great. I wish I could give you more than just a checkmark for a correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: :-) not too worry - good luck with your project!

Comment: I have seen presentation where large companies do over 100,000 - A really good article on 3rd party services that can help and work with CIVI can be found here https://civicrm.org/blog/andrewhunt/alternatives-to-mandrill